# How do I create x lists in Python (e.g. with a while-loop)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, while-loop

I would like to create lists in Python but not create each one individually by hand.
Instead, I want to create `X` lists. So the number of lists depends on `X`.

Is that possible for example with a while-loop? And of course, every list should have a different name.

For example: `List_1`, `List_2`, `List_3` ... `List_x`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the only option is to make a list and then append other lists to that list. For example, the code could look like this:

```
Big_List=[]

x = 0
while x < 100:
    Big_List.append([])
    x = x+1
```

Then such a list is created in which you can selectively navigate to the individual lists:

> Big_List=[[],[],[],[],[],[]]

You can then append something to the 10th list, for example:

```
Big_List[9].append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a `list`/`dict` that contain the amount of lists desired?

something like:

```
[[] for _ in range(3)]
```

Or:

```
{x:[] for x in range(3)}
```

Then you can access each "list_i" that you desire by indexing/key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not that advanced yet. So if I understood that correctly, 3 different lists were generated, right? And what are the names of the individual lists? Thanks again

Comment: @IlovePython in the first option there is no "name" to the list. In the second option you could refer the key values as names (but they arent).  you create **1** variable with a certain name with multiple lists and then just accessing each list

Answer (score 0):

Either you create them by hand or you virtually create a list from lists. I think this is the easiest way. Unfortunately you cannot name the lists in the lists. Actually there is no other way.  Variable names in variables just do not work!